# Update query when database in ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

My update query

```
 update tbl_Clients set  Username=@Username, Password=@Password where Id=@Id
```

When I am updating this code in giving error Syntax error in update statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason might because `Passowrd` is a [*reserved keyword*](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) in MS Access. You should use it with square brackets like `[Password]`

```
update tbl_Clients set Username = @Username, [Password] = @Password where Id = @Id
```

As a best practice, change it to *non-reserved* word.

By the way, if you using `OleDb` provider, it doesn't *care* about the named parameters. It only care about their orders. Since you didn't show your code, I hope you provided your parameters in a same order that you defined in your command. Like;

```
var cmd = OleDbCommand("update tbl_Clients set Username = @Username, [Password] = @Password where Id = @Id");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Username;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Password;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Id;
```

Comment: I have same order as in command   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Id; cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Username;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Password;

Comment: @Vampire No, **you are not**. Look at your command, you defined as `@Username, @Password, @Id` order in it. But you try to add your parameters with `@Id, @Username, @Password` order. Their order **must** be the same.

Comment: Yes  I thought id must be at first. as sql

Comment: In general, I prefer to prefix field / column names with a table alias, it saves trying to remember all those reserved words.

Comment: @Fionnuala Hmm, that's definitely sounds a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

For MS Access you use a question mark ("?") in order to reference parameters in a query, so:

```
update tbl_Clients set Username=?, Password=? where Id=?
```

Of course you must be careful to add the parameters to the command object in the same order as they appear in the query. See [this blog post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access) for some examples.

Comment: not working again giving same error, I have same order

Comment: You can call the parameters anything you like, as long as you understand that it is only the order that matters, not the name.

Comment: Exactly. Using `?` is **not** have to. MSDN page is wrong about that.